# Top Image Zooming effect in ScrollViewer in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, .net-5

How can I add the "Top Image Zooming while scrolling effect in UWP. I'm using .NET5 with C# 10. XAML representation would be better. Anyone Help me. Please reference the below gif link.

The link of the gif is [here](https://i.imgur.com/brrICgQ.mp4).

Comment: If you're using .NET 5 with C# 10, why have you tagged .NET Framework (`[.net]`) instead of .NET 5 (`[.net5]`) and why have you tagged `[C#-4.0]`?

Comment: oops, I'll rectify it now

Comment: Is that a UWP app? As far as I know, UWP doesn't support .net 5 and c#10

Comment: It's new version of UWP for win11, Beta testing.

Comment: Do you mean winui 3 UWP ?

Comment: yeah, that's right

Comment: The behavior is made with Composition Animation. It's made by three keyframe animations that target Scale, Offset, and Opacity using Composition API. There is a similar effect called Shy Header, You could check the [Windows Composition Samples](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-composition-samples/9n1h8czhbpxb?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) and the source code is here: [WindowsCompositionSamples-Github](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples). You need to check the sample about how to use these animations If you want to implement the same behavior in your app

Comment: Thanks a lot bruh, that helped me, what I was lookin for is called, "sticky Header".

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear. There is no existing code example for the behavior you want in the `Windows Composition Samples`. The reason why I told you to take a look at `shy header` is that you could take that as a reference so that you could try to make your own behavior similar to what you've seen in the Store app.